# HAproxy health check underlying application

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I am using NGINX reverproxy on 3 servers to password protect an app. nginx holds the port 80 on a server and app runs on localhost port x. nginx fwds requests to port x from client hitting a vip:vipport.

I have a vip on server 1, keld by keepalived and haproxy does the LB and health check against port 80 on all 3 servers. I am looking at the interface, and taking down the application doesnt turn the server row red as the nginx port is still up .. is there any way for ha to accurately represent the application port turning off?

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global


    log         127.0.0.1 local0 notice         # only send important events

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy.app
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.app.pid
    user        haproxy
    group       users
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy.elasticsearch/stats level admin

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    tcp
    log                     global
    option                  tcplog
    option                  dontlognull

    timeout connect         4s
    timeout server          30s
    timeout client          30s

    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           30s
    timeout http-keep-alive 5s
    timeout check           5s
    maxconn                 10000

frontend front
        mode tcp
        bind ipin:vipport
        default_backend back


backend back
        balance leastconn
        source ipin
        #balance roundrobin
        #option ssl-hello-chk
        stick-table type ip size 200k expire 60m
        stick on src

        server server3 ip:80 check
        server server2 ip:80 check
        server server1 ip:80 check

listen stats
        bind *:99
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats uri /
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you have a separate health check route in your application server, and periodically hit that route instead of just checking if port is up. This will help you monitor actual application port instead of NGINX.

At HAProxy, this can be achieved by injecting a simple Lua script, which hits the end point, checks status and based on it, mark if server is up.

You will be able to find some sample Lua scripts for HAProxy [here](https://github.com/zareenc/haproxy-lua-examples).

Comment: I dont think this will work as .. these ports are attached to localhost on said servers.. this is why nginx is in place, its a proxy pass from hostname:port to localhost:port with a auth layer in between. HA is in place to do high availability. Some time HA pings nginx on a server where the app is down and we get a bad reply.